# What is the difference between "core" and "total" quality in dwarf fortress 40d?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> This is in reference to Dwarf Fortress 40d (v0.28.181.40d). Later versions of this game may have significantly changed the related mechanics.

When setting up a stockpile for furniture or finished goods there is a setting for Core Quality and Total Quality... what's the difference?

I'd like to set up a series of stockpiles in increasing distance from the trade depot and increasing quality (so I can give them the crappiest stuff first and save the best for use in the fortress)... but the two different ratings for quality has me confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *believe* that core quality refers to the item itself - i.e., a superior-crafted door, and total quality takes into account the *masterfully encrusted with blue diamonds* and other miscellanea.

I've been using "Core Quality" for a furniture stockpile of masterwork doors (admittedly, in 31.16) and only masterwork doors are going to that pile.

Comment: This is correct, more details can be found here: http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Item_quality#Quality_levels_in_stockpile_settings and here: http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=96501.0